# How to create xmpp group chat and add members using smack 4.1 in android

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, groupchat

In my app, I want to create groups and add users to the groups using smack 4.1.
I am able to create group but unable to add user in that groups.
My Code for create groups is...

*create group*

```
if (connection != null) {
        String groupName = XmppUtils.buildMUCName(grpName);
        MultiUserChat multiUserChat = managerMuc.getMultiUserChat(groupName);
        if (!multiUserChat.isJoined()) {
            boolean createNow;
            try {
                multiUserChat.createOrJoin(grpName);
                createNow = true;
                if (createNow) {
                    Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
                    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
                    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", grpName); //                        form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", userDate.getUserId().toString() + "@" + Config.ChatValues.SERVICE_NAME);
                    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
                    List<String> cast_values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    cast_values.add("moderator");
                    cast_values.add("participant");
                    cast_values.add("visitor");
                    form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_presencebroadcast", cast_values);
                    multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(form);
                    multiUserChat.join(userDate.getUserId().toString() + "@" + Config.ChatValues.SERVICE_NAME); //                        multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(DataForm.Type.submit)); //this is to create the room immediately after join.
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("createGroup", "=======multiUserChat.isJoined()=====>");
        }
    }
```

Code for add users
*this is what I am doing  to add users*

```
  // Create a MultiUserChat using an XMPPConnection for a room

   String roomName = groupName + "@" + Config.ChatValues.GROUP_SERVICE_NAME;
    MultiUserChat muc2 = managerMuc.getMultiUserChat(roomName);
    // User2 joins the new room
    // The room service will decide the amount of history to send
    // The number of chat room services will decide to accept the historical record
   /* DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
    history.setMaxStanzas(0);*/

    //history.setSince(new Date());
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedLisrArray.size(); i++) {
            String userId = selectedLisrArray.get(i).userId.toString() + "@" + Config.ChatValues.SERVICE_NAME;
            Log.e("joinGroups", "=========>" + roomName + " users to join  " + userId);

            muc2.invite(msg, userId, "let's  join this room ");
            muc2.sendMessage(userId + " : You have joined the group : " + roomName);
        }

    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: hi what did you study and tried so for for group chat ?

Comment: i am able to create group but unable to add  user in that group

Comment: then post your code that you have tried, how can other people understand what is your issue and why you are not able to add user in chat?

Comment: you should go for conference and add users in room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done little bit same.Just you send invitation and then install plugin Subscription on openfire if you used.Change settings to accept any request.

If you not using openfire then you just accept their invitation on other side.
Hope this will help you.

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(getActivity()), groupname);
                try {
                    muc.create(StringUtils.parseName(XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(getActivity()).getUser()));
                    muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                } catch (NoResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < alSelectedContacts.size(); i++) {

                    Log.e("tag", "group chating purpose1 ::" + alSelectedContacts.get(i).get("id"));
                    try {
                        muc.invite((alSelectedContacts.get(i).get("id") + "_user") + "@" + XMPP.HOST,
                                alSelectedContacts.get(i).get("id") + "_user");
                    } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                try {
                    muc.sendMessage("New group created");
                } catch (NotConnectedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**Get Muc invitation here,**

```
MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(mXmppConnection,
        new InvitationListener() {

            @Override
            public void invitationReceived(Connection connection,
                    String room, String inviter, String reason,
                    String unKnown, Message message) {

                //MultiUserChat.decline(mXmppConnection, room, inviter,
                    //  "Don't bother me right now");
                // MultiUserChat.decline(mXmppConnection, room, inviter,
                // "Don't bother me right now");
                try {
                   muc.join("test-nick-name");
                   Log.e("abc","join room successfully");
                   muc.sendMessage("I joined this room!! Bravo!!");
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Log.e("abc","join room failed!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: how other user get this invitation and how he can accept

Comment: Invitation get as a message and after just need to call this,  muc.join("test-nick-name");

Comment: i have edited my answer please check.

Comment: i have to add this addInvitationListener after user login ?

Comment: yes, make sure you connected with server

Comment: did you able to solve your problem ?

Comment: hi saveen, other  user is not getting ma invitation when i am inviting others

Comment: same way isn't working ? and which one server you used, openfire or some other ?

Comment: this is what iam receiving when i invite others......................D/SMACK: SENT (0): <message to='booom shiva@conference.ip-175-02-2-97' id='7t3CC-23' type='groupchat'><body>HELLO guys Join this group</body><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><invite to='89@ip-175-02-2-97'><reason>let&apos;s  join this room </reason></invite></x></message>

Comment: using openfire 4.0.2

Comment: you want to accept request of invitation ?

Comment: if not then install plugin subscription then go to server settings then Subscription Service Properties --> accept and all then it to be save

Comment: one more things get this body if body contain your standard text like "HELLO guys Join this group" then just user to join that group.. muc.join(groupname)

Comment: other user is not receiving any invitation if  i am able to receive invitation from other side then  i will  accept invitation

Comment: please check your id's is it correct ?

Comment: can you provide me plugin link

Comment: i have added plugin let me try  again

Comment: yes sure.. please take a reference from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384627/android-accept-invitation-of-group-chat-by-using-xmpp

Comment: thanks bro, now i am able to get invitation and also able to accept

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: can we add group image  in xmpp

Comment: yes, you can do but i have no exact idea. I have done this in different way by using custom extension.

Comment: user removed from group after reconnecting  any solution

Comment: whenever user again come online, check list of groups and join that all groups

Comment: There is no specific way in conference

Comment: ok thnks now iam  receiving  this exception while trying to fetch joined rooms org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: item-not-found - cancel