# Smack Api Group not working

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I am trying to create Group using Smack Api
 
I use the following code
It crashes on `muc#roomconfig_roomowners` tag
If i remove that line, it works fine, Group creates
But no group is assigned to the current user, no one is owner

```
    public void createGroup() {
        MultiUserChat chatRoom = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).getMultiUserChat("room719@conference." + MYSITE);
        try {
            chatRoom.create("room719");
            Form form = chatRoom.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
            form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
            form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", "room719");
//            List owners = new ArrayList();
//            owners.add("currUser@"+MYSITE);
            form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", Arrays.asList("currUser@"+MYSITE));
            form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
            chatRoom.sendConfigurationForm(form);
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: whose ever create group that person is already owner by default.There is no need to do any extra thing.

Comment: take a look from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988799/how-to-create-group-chat-and-add-user-using-smack-4-1-in-android

Comment: @saveen i tried with get groups function from user, it doesn't show anything, shows empty array

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me, can you try this?

```
 if( !chatRoom.isJoined() ){
       chatRoom.createOrJoin("your nickname");
       List<String> owners = new ArrayList<String>();
       owners.add("currUser@"+MYSITE);
       Form form = chatRoom.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
       form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", "your roomname");
       form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
       form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
       form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
       chatRoom.sendConfigurationForm(form);
    }
```